# How put specifical characters in sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

i'm doing a sql base with python3 and i add some people on my base.
I just have a problem with 2 people: someone who has a "'" and someone who has a ")"

```
        # execut = "INSERT INTO users VALUES(Rafagraph | Notion'Art#0739, 272125469544022027, Rafagraph | Notion'Art, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.0)"
        # cur.execute(execut)



        # execut = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('CmoipastoiB#9926)', '703280156197912736', 'CmoipastoiB-)', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.0)"
        # cur.execute(execut)
```

i tried like in print (' \ ' ') but that doesn't function.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries - see for example: https://stackabuse.com/a-sqlite-tutorial-with-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parameterize your SQL, otherwise you're vulnerable to SQL injection. Imagine if someone's name contained valid SQL statements: you would end up executing that, which could be bad.

```py
statement = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
values = (a, b, c)
cur.execute(statement, values)
```

This will properly escape the values into the executed SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! it works! i had heard this "injection" but didn't know how to protect it. ty